# Continuous deployment to my local IIS from azure devops

Tags: iis, azure-devops

I have created project and repo on Azure Devops. The repo is a copy of a wwwroot folder on a coldfusion deployment on IIS, which is on a locally-housed server. I can't understand how to set up a pipeline that copies commits from the repo to the local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first make sure that the Azure pipelines can reach your server or setup a self hosted agent. Then you can create a trigger that when a pull request is done or a merge to for example your master branch a pipeline runs with creates and artificat and a PowerShell script who copies that to your server. Or just an upload task in a build pipeline.

Here is a example pipeline which runs on a hosted ado agent.

```yaml
trigger:
- '*'  # Trigger the pipeline on all branches, you can customize this as needed

pr:
- '*'  # Trigger the pipeline on all pull requests

pool:
  name: 'NameOfYourSelfHostedAgentPool'  # Replace with the name of your agent pool
  demands:
  - agent.os -equals Windows_NT  # Optional: Ensure it runs on Windows-based agents

steps:
- script: |
    # Your build steps here (e.g., compile, test)
  displayName: 'Build and Test'

- script: |
    # Copy files to the remote server using PowerShell
    $sourcePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/path/to/source/files"
    $destinationPath = "\\remote-server\destination\path"

    Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $destinationPath -Recurse -Force
  displayName: 'Copy Files to Remote Server'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Additional tasks or scripts to run on the remote server (if needed)
  displayName: 'Additional Remote Server Tasks'
```

In this configuration:

1. In the `pool` section, specify the name of your self-hosted agent pool (`name: 'NameOfYourSelfHostedAgentPool'`). You should replace `'NameOfYourSelfHostedAgentPool'` with the actual name of your agent pool.
2. Optionally, you can use the `demands` section to specify conditions for the agent that the pipeline should run on. In the example above, it ensures that the agent is running a Windows operating system. Adjust this as needed for your agent setup.
3. The rest of the pipeline configuration remains the same as in the previous example.

Make sure you have already set up and registered your self-hosted agent on your on-premises server and that it is associated with the agent pool specified in the YAML configuration. The agent should be online and capable of running Windows-based tasks like PowerShell scripts.

I wouldn't copy the commits, but instead after a pull request, so you have the option let someone validate the changes or add automatic tests

Comment: Thanks, this clarified things. I was trying to user a deployment group rather than agent pool. One additional question:  $sourcePath is an azure repo, how do I identify the path?

Comment: That is made by a variable, `$sourcePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)``. which something default in Azure Devops.The root dir of your repo/branch (predefined variable)

Comment: System.DefaultWorkingDirectory 
The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. For example: c:\agent_work\1\s

By default, new build pipelines update only the changed files. You can modify how files are downloaded on the Repository tab.

This variable is agent-scoped. It can be used as an environment variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task, but not as part of the build number or as a version control tag. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Do you know why it is running "Checkout test@main to s" (where test is the project name and main is the repo branch) rather than immediately copying to the remote server?